# My code(Android) got SQLite injection warning but I can't find it

Tags: android, security

My code was scanned by a program, warnings comes out

> SQL injection vulnerability found in Android app

Findings Descriptions

> ```
> The Android app was found to have SQL injection vulnerability; attackers could submit crafted request to manipulate the database
> ```
>
> queries / commands.
>
> ```
> This code uses concatenated query in sql statement which is prone to sqlite injection. Suggest using parameterized query instead.
> ```

I have already used binding in the query statement. Is that the native SQLiteDataBase.query not good enough to prevent the SQL injection?

***Here is my code***

```
    public class TypeModel implements DataBaseConstant{

        private SQLiteDatabase r_db;
        public TypeModel(Context context) {
            // Get the Singleton database from static method
            this.r_db = DataBase.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public void addType(int id ,  ArrayMap<String,String> nameMap){
                for(String key : nameMap.keySet()){
                    ContentValues mType = new ContentValues();
                    mType.put(TypeConstant.ID, id);
                    mType.put(TypeConstant.LANG,key);
                    mType.put(TypeConstant.NAME,nameMap.get(key));
                    this.r_db.insert(HadDataBaseConstant.HOTEL_TYPE_TABLE, null, mType);
                }
        }
        public boolean isExist(int id){
             String[] m_columns = {
                     TypeConstant.ID
                    };
                    String whereClause = TypeConstant.ID+" = ? ";
                    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(id)
                        };
                    Cursor cursor = this.r_db .query(HOTEL_TYPE_TABLE, m_columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        cursor.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    return false;

        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> search(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs ){
            ArrayList<Integer> childList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             String[] m_columns = {
                     TypeConstant.ID
                    };


                    Cursor cursor =null;

                    try{
                        cursor = this.r_db .query(true,HOTEL_TYPE_TABLE, m_columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null,null);
                            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                                int childId = cursor.getInt(0);
                                childList.add(childId);
                        }
                    }finally{
                           if( cursor!=null )
                                cursor.close();
                    }


            return childList;

        }
        public  ArrayMap<String,String>  getType(int id){
            ArrayMap<String,String> nameMap = new ArrayMap<String,String>();
               String[] m_columns = {
                       TypeConstant.LANG,
                       TypeConstant.NAME
                    };
                String whereClause = TypeConstant.ID+" = ? ";
                String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
                        String.valueOf(id)
                    };
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try{
                        cursor = this.r_db .query(HOTEL_TYPE_TABLE, m_columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
                        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                            String lang = cursor.getString(0);
                            String name = cursor.getString(1);
                            nameMap.put(lang,name);
                        }
                    }finally{
                       if( cursor!=null )
                            cursor.close();
                    }



                    return nameMap;


        }

    }
```

The program has some reference

> OWASP Guidelines, http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Input
>   OWASP Guidelines, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection Data
>   Validation,
>   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation#Delimiter_and_special_characters
>   Unixwiz.net Tech Tips,
>   http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html